# mail is send success but not receiving mail using codeigniter (Godday Email(Shared Server))

Tags: php, codeigniter, email

```
$config = Array(
    'protocol' => 'mail',
    'smtp_host' => 'mail.salefiesta.com',
    'smtp_port' => 587,
    'smtp_user' => 'info@salefista.com',
    'smtp_pass' => 'password',
    'mailtype'  => 'html', 
    'charset'=>'iso-8859-1',
    'wordwrap' => TRUE
);
$this->load->library('email', $config);
$this->email->set_newline("\r\n");
$this->email->from('info@salefista.com','salefiesta');
$this->email->to('brijeshdubeyid@gmail.com');
$this->email->message("Hello Brijesh"); 
if ($this->email->send()) {
    echo "success";
    echo $this->email->print_debugger();
} else {
    echo "fail";
}
```

Please help me to solve issue.

Please check and let me know where i am wrong.

Thank you

Comment: try `show_error($this->email->print_debugger());` in the `else` part

Comment: it tried but it also enter in if condition not else part

Comment: then ask godaay hosting provider to check your mail server settings and logs

Answer (score 0):

i think the issue is with the `smtp_host` that you set. i had the same issue before, then i tried to use the relay server that godaddy specified which is something like `smtp_host=>'<relayserver>.prod.sin2.secureserver.net'`, and it worked well.

edit: by the way godaddy mail servers are notorious for being slow and unreliable, and they wont allow you to use any other mail server like gmail [i posted this problem](https://ph.godaddy.com/community/cPanel-Hosting/cPanel-emails-are-delayed-or-not-arriving/td-p/114185?isc=gocommaasr) on their forum before but without any help

edit: another thing that i noticed is that you did not specified smtp_crypto which is set as null by default.

here is my complete configuration

```
$config = array(
    'protocol' => 'mail',
    'smtp_host' => '<relayserver>.prod.sin2.secureserver.net',
    'smtp_port' => 465,
    'smtp_user' => 'info@salefista.com',
    'smtp_pass' => 'password',
    'mailtype'  => 'html', 
    'smtp_crypto'  => 'ssl', 
    'charset'=>'iso-8859-1',
    'wordwrap' => TRUE
);
```

note: this should also work at local server (i tested it).

Comment: can you please send full configuration of email (still not working).